# Issues configuring scons to use posix arguments in a windows command prompt

Tags: build, makefile, scons

First off I should forewarn you that I am a new grad(and EE at that), and not terribly familiar a build process more advanced than my hello world programs.

My issue is: We are attempting to use SCons ton build our project at work.  Our compiler is called 'i686-pc-elf-gcc' and uses posix style command line arguments.  But whenever I try and use scons it forces Windows arguments, so instead of:

```
i686-pc-elf-gcc -o hello.o -c hello.cpp
```

I get

```
i686-pc-elf-gcc /Fohello.obj /c hello.cpp /TP /nologo
```

Which our compiler doesn't like.
Here is what my SConscript file looks like

```
import os

path = ['c:\\compiler\GCC\i686\bin',
    '../../build/include']

env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : path,'TEMP' : os.environ['TEMP']})
env.Replace(CC = "i686-pc-elf-gcc")
env['platform'] = 'posix'

env.Program('hello.cpp')
```

The environment is in a DOS prompt with cygwin installed.  I was hoping setting the platform to posix was all that was needed, but I have been beating my head against the wall  with no results.

Comment: There ain't no "DOS prompt" any more. And sheesh, people complain about make's syntax!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the default SCons compiler detection is picking up the Microsoft compiler suite. Instead of:

```
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : path,'TEMP' : os.environ['TEMP']})
```

maybe try:

```
env = Environment(tools = ['gcc', 'g++', 'gnulink'],
                  ENV = {'PATH' : path,'TEMP' : os.environ['TEMP']})
```

This way it will use the gcc toolset instead of the msvc one. If you only overwrite CC then all the flags are still MSVC style, while the compiler is really GNU. So the full SConstruct would be:

```
import os
path = [r'c:\compiler\GCC\i686\bin', '../../build/include']
env = Environment(tools = ['gcc', 'g++', 'gnulink'],
                  ENV = {'PATH' : path,'TEMP' : os.environ['TEMP']})
env.Replace(CC = "i686-pc-elf-gcc")
env.Program('hello.cpp')
```

Comment: @Andy, that happens when the command is "-o hello.o...", the "-" means "ignore errors". You still have to set env[CC] I imagine, otherwise if your GCC isn't in the path it'll probably be empty.